# Representing common information on edges

Tags: r, graph

I have data that looks like this

```
GPS -> accurate, lost, quality
Battery ->  draining, hog, drain 
Screen ->   flickering, off
Signal ->   lost, quality
```

Now I want to generate a graph that connects two nodes if they share some common information and does not connect the nodes if they don't share anything. The representation of the graph for the above data  is as follows:

[image]

Any clue how to achieve this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Graph

Define the input as shown in `Lines` and transform it so that we can read it into data frame `DF` and then split into list `s`.  Then create `ea` which is a three column matrix containing possible edges defined by vertices `from`,  vertices `to` and edge label `edge_label`.  Edges with no label are set to have an edge_label of NA and then we drop all rows having NAs giving matrix `e`.  Finally create graph `g` and plot it.

(This data could alternately be represented using a bipartite graph as discussed in the Bipartite Graph section after the graph.)

```
library(igraph)

# input
Lines <- "GPS -> accurate, lost, quality
Battery ->  draining, hog, drain 
Screen ->   flickering, off
Signal ->   lost, quality"

L <- sub(" ->", ",", readLines(textConnection(Lines)))
DF <- read.table(text = L, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE, 
  strip.white = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

# split DF into a list, s, whose components are named using DF[[1]]
s <- lapply(split(as.matrix(DF[, -1]), DF[[1]]), Filter, f = nzchar)

Intersect <- function(x) toString(intersect(s[[x[1]]], s[[x[2]]]))
ea <- cbind(t(combn(names(s), 2)), combn(names(s), 2, Intersect))
colnames(ea) <- c("from", "to", "edge.label")
e <- na.omit(replace(ea, !nzchar(ea), NA))

# create graph and plot
g <- graph_from_data_frame(e, vertices = names(s), directed = FALSE)
plot(g, edge.label = e[, "edge.label"], 
  vertex.color = "white", vertex.size = 35, edge.color = "black")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Bipartite Graph

Another approach is to create a bipartite graph.

```
gg <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(table(stack(s)))
plot(gg, layout = layout_as_bipartite)
```

### Update

Simplify.  Add bipartite graph section.